# Calculus (Spivak), Ch. 2 ex. 6

Tags: calculus

this is the exercise: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxdtw.jpg). I am trying to undrestand how author came to the conclusion under line, the $(n+1)^3 - n^3 = 3[1^2+...+n^2] + 3[1+...+n] + n$, how it follows from previous statements. I've already spent 2 hours trying to figure it out, could someone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: It's a telescoping sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add $$2^3-1^3=3\times1^2+3\times1+1$$

$$3^3-2^3=3\times2^2+3\times2+1$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$.$$

$$n^3-(n-1)^3=3(n-1)^2+3(n-1)+1$$

$$(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+1$$

to get

$(n+1)^3-n^3+n^3-(n-1)^3+\dots+3^3-2^3+2^3-1^3$

$$=3(1+\dots+n^2)+3(1+\dots+n)+(1+\dots+1),$$

which simplifies to $(n+1)^3-1^3=3[1+\dots+n^2]+3[1+\dots+n]+n$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up $$(n+1)^3-n^3=3n^2+3n+2$$

from $1$ to $k$ you get $$3(1^2+2^2...+k^2)+3(1+2+3+...+k)+(1+1+1+...+1)$$